# How send email with BCC header via GMAIL API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-client

How can I send email with BCC via GMAIL API? I send emails to TO or CC but BCC doesn't work. I use `Base64.urlsafe_encode64(email.to_s)`and this code create string without BCC. My working code example:

```
    email = Mail.new
    email.date = Time.now
    email.subject = subject
    email.to = email_array_to_email_to(to)
    email.cc = email_array_to_email_to(cc)
    email.bcc = email_array_to_email_to(bcc)
    email.reply_to = email_array_to_email_to(reply_to)
    email.html_part do
      body message
    end
    request = {
        api_method: @google_api.users.messages.to_h['gmail.users.messages.send'],
        parameters: { userId: 'me' },
        body_object: {
            raw: Base64.urlsafe_encode64(email.to_s)
        },
    }
```

Do I have to call again GMAIL API and send this email with thread id and BCC as TO? 
I use [google-api-client](https://rubygems.org/gems/google-api-client) 0.7.1

EDIT:
Mail object:

```
#<Mail::Message:70336725981360,
Multipart: true,
Headers: <Date: Tue,
01 Dec 2015 14:09:08 +0100>,
<Reply-To: >,
<To: ["quatermain32 <my_email@gmail.com>"]>,
<Cc: ["quatermain32 <my_email@gmail.com>"]>,
<Bcc: ["my_email@gmail.com"]>,
<Subject: Test subject>,
<Content-Type: multipart/mixed>>
```

Mail object with `to_s`:

```
"Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2015 14:09:08 +0100\r\n
To: my_email <my_email@gmail.com>\r\n
Cc: my_email <my_email@gmail.com>\r\n
Message-ID: <565d9c6e3cf0b_058b7@Olivers-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>\r\n
Subject: Test subject\r\n
Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n
 boundary=\"--==_mimepart_565d9bf468e77_cb0d35e200577a\";\r\n
 charset=UTF-8\r\n
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
----==_mimepart_565d9bf468e77_cb0d3ff88645e200577a\r\n
Content-Type: text/html;\r\n
 charset=UTF-8\r\n
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n
\r\n
<p>Test content</p>\r\n
----==_mimepart_565d9bf468e77_cb0d3ff88645e200577a--\r\n
"
```

Comment: Could you show us how `email.to_s` looks before encoding it?

Comment: @Tholle yes, I added it to question. Is it ok?

Comment: It seems like your `<Bcc: ["my_email@gmail.com"]>` in the `Mail object` is wrong. Try `<Bcc: ["<my_email@gmail.com>"]>` instead.

Comment: it's same
```=> #<Mail::Message:70354473411500, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2015 16:29:10 +0100>, <Reply-To: >, <To: ["Kriska Quatermain <kriska@quatermain.org>"]>, <Cc: >, <Bcc: ["oliver@techvoxinc.com <oliver@techvoxinc.com>"]>, <Subject: test bad bcc 2>, <Content-Type: multipart/mixed>>
[2] pry(#<GoogleApi::Gmail::Message>)> email.bcc
=> ["oliver@techvoxinc.com"]
[3] pry(#<GoogleApi::Gmail::Message>)> email.to
=> ["kriska@quatermain.org"]
```

Comment: Darnet :( Try `<Bcc: ["<oliver@techvoxinc.com>"]>`, not `<Bcc: ["oliver@techvoxinc.com <oliver@techvoxinc.com>"]>`. Otherwise I don't know, sorry.

Comment: nope. It's same. I read it's because email protocol doesn't allow to show bcc in raw email and this is raw email. So I can do second request to google api, but I think it's the last option. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You have to manually add the bcc header to the email, it will not be sent to the recipients. Same as gmail-ruby-api does it https://github.com/jhk753/gmail-ruby-api/blob/e0d62a751bc31397926c5800532f26e185e00b16/lib/gmail/message.rb

```
encoded = mail.encoded
if bcc = mail.bcc.join(",").presence
  encoded.prepend "Bcc: #{bcc}\n"
end
... send email ...
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  The Mail gem discards the Bcc header when you call `.encoded` on it, which is what ultimately happens during `mail.to_s`.